# SAP ERP Plant Maintenance - Close an open manual call

Tags: sap-erp

I have very little SAP ERP knowledge.  I wrote some code to create a Manual Call Work Order in the Plant Maintenance module.  The code seems to have worked but when I try to create another manual call work order I get an error message saying I already have one open.  I know there are transactions I can run to show me the open call and allow me to close it.  Can you tell me a transaction I can use to close the open manual call?  All I know is the Maintenance Plan Number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone here showed me how to close the open manual call.  I'm adding the instructions here for completeness sake.

1. Run transaction ip03.
2. Enter the MaintenancePlan number and press enter.
3. Select the Manual maintenance schedule calls tab.
4. Highlight the row with the open manual call.
5. Click the eye glasses icon under the table.
6. Select the order number and copy it.
7. Run transaction iw32.
8. The order number you copied should be in the selected.  If not enter your order number and press enter.
9. Click on the checkered flag icon to
   TECO the order and clear the open
   manual call.

After doing these steps I was able to create another manual work order call.

Answer (score 0):

Try transaction IW23.  If you press F4 on the notification field you will get a wider selection that allows you to enter Maintenance Plan number.

Transaction IP03 allows you to look at a maintenance plan.